# Spring / Thymeleaf: Property or field 'title' cannot be found on null. Why?

Tags: spring-mvc, highcharts, thymeleaf, spelevaluationexception

The application throws org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'title' cannot be found on null

and I can't understand why...
Here is the html snippet, called by the master.

```
<title th:fragment="title">Surveys Feed</title>
<div th:fragment="content" th:each="surv : ${allSurveys}" >
    <div id="surv-ct" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px;     height:400px; margin: 0 auto">
    <script th:inline="javascript">
       /*<![CDATA[*/
           $('#surv-ct').highcharts({
               chart: {
                   type: 'bar'
               },
               title: {
                   text: [[${surv.title}]]
               },
             // ... other stuff 
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yet when the application is launched, the field title isn't null!
Here we have the mapping fot the object allSurveys, which takes all the surveys from the repo and returns a list.

```
@ModelAttribute("allSurveys")
public List<Survey> allSurveys() {
    List<Survey> surveys = new Surveys(repo.findAll()).getSurveys();
    // print surveys titles
    for (int i = 0; i < surveys.size(); i++) {
        Survey sur = surveys.get(i);
        System.out.println("Survey info: " + sur.getTitle());
    }
    return surveys;
}
```

As proof we can see that the surveys' titles are printed on the console:
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcFM0.jpg)

And they are PRESENT in the database
[Surveys Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXJA0.jpg)

So why does it say that is null? I have seen different answers on the internet but none seems to be a solution for my case.

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT:
On suggestion I tried to print the object ${surv}. I changed the "surv-ct" attribute of the inner div from ID to class since they are supposed many.

```
<div th:fragment="content" th:each="surv : ${allSurveys}" >
    <div class="surv-ct" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
        <p>Object is: <span th:text=${surv}>obj</span></p>
        <!--
        <script th:inline="javascript">
           /*<![CDATA[*/

               $('.surv-ct').highcharts({
                   chart: {
                       type: 'bar'
                   },
                   // ... more code
    -->
    </div>
</div>
```

When I analize the code on Mozilla, this is the result.

```
    <p>Object is: <span></span></p>
    <!--
    <script th:inline="javascript">
       /*<![CDATA[*/
           $('.surv-ct').highcharts({
                // ... more code that i deleted
                // it's commented anyway
      -->
```

First of all, only one result is printed. And secondly it doesn't get any surv object. That's why the field "title" is null I guess.
So why is the object null then? Any suggestion?

Comment: Something I would do to debug this would be to remove the `[[${surv.title}]]` for a while and instead print only the `${surv}` somewhere. This way you will see which surveys are null (because it's one or more of the surveys being null, not titles), if the size of the survey list is accurate etc.

Comment: Generally title should be text, but in your case seems to be text in nested array.

Comment: Nope, that's javascript-thymeleaf notation (apparently). [See here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is because you're using `th:include` when you're using the fragment. According to the [Thymeleaf Documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#difference-between-thinclude-and-threplace):

> Whereas th:include will include the contents of the fragment into its host tag, th:replace will actually substitute the host tag by the fragment’s

This means your `th:each` will just be ignored - explaining why you're only seeing the one result printed.

The solution is to use `th:replace`, which will make use of the `th:if`. Or you can change the format of your fragment slightly, so that the `th:each` is part of the fragment content. eg:

```
<th:block th:fragment="content">
    <div th:each="surv : ${allSurveys}">
        <div id="surv-ct" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px;     height:400px; margin: 0 auto">
            <script th:inline="javascript">
               /*<![CDATA[*/
                   $('#surv-ct').highcharts({
                       chart: {
                           type: 'bar'
                       },
                       title: {
                           text: [[${surv.title}]]
                       },
                     // ... other stuff 
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</th:block>
```